# Android Studio: An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_152-release)

Tags: java, android, compilation

While running app, unable to complete compilation. 
Keep throwing error.

I am using dagger2 library for annotation.

> Error:15:04:36.466 [ERROR] [system.err] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_152-release). Please file a bug against the
>   Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page
>   (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database
>   (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the
>   following diagnostic in your report. Thank you. 15:04:36.466 [ERROR]
>   [system.err] java.lang.NullPointerException 15:04:36.466 [ERROR]
>   [system.err]  at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check$1AnnotationValidator.visitAnnotation(Check.java:2657)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCAnnotation.accept(JCTree.java:2317)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.visitAnnotation(TreeScanner.java:320)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check$1AnnotationValidator.visitAnnotation(Check.java:2658)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCAnnotation.accept(JCTree.java:2317)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.validateAnnotationTree(Check.java:2663)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.validateAnnotation(Check.java:2730)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.validateAnnotations(Check.java:2717)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter$6.run(MemberEnter.java:891)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:155)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512) 15:04:36.467
>   [ERROR] [system.err]  at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471) 15:04:36.467
>   [ERROR] [system.err]  at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
>   15:04:36.467 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523) 15:04:36.468
>   [ERROR] [system.err]  at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
>   15:04:36.468 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
>   15:04:36.468 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:49)
>   15:04:36.468 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
>   15:04:36.468 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:99)
>   15:04:36.468 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
>   15:04:36.468 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
>   15:04:36.468 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
>   15:04:36.468 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
>   15:04:36.469 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:198)
>   15:04:36.469 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:183)
>   15:04:36.469 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:120)
>   15:04:36.469 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:95)
>   15:04:36.469 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   15:04:36.476 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   15:04:36.476 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   15:04:36.476 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 15:04:36.476 [ERROR]
>   [system.err]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>   15:04:36.476 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
>   15:04:36.476 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>   15:04:36.476 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>   15:04:36.476 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>   15:04:36.487 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   15:04:36.487 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   15:04:36.487 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>   15:04:36.487 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>   15:04:36.487 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>   15:04:36.487 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>   15:04:36.487 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   15:04:36.497 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   15:04:36.498 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>   15:04:36.526 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   15:04:36.527 [ERROR] [system.err]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 15:04:36.815 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  15:04:36.815
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 15:04:36.815 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  15:04:36.815
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] *
>   What went wrong: 15:04:36.815 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution
>   failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. 15:04:36.815 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Compilation
>   failed; see the compiler error output for details. 15:04:36.815
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   15:04:36.815 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception
>   is: 15:04:36.815 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. 15:04:36.815 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>   15:04:36.815 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>   15:04:36.816 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException:
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:51)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:99)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:198)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:183)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:120)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:95)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>   15:04:36.817 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   15:04:36.818 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   15:04:36.818 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>   15:04:36.818 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>   15:04:36.818 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>   15:04:36.818 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>   15:04:36.818 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  ... 27 more
>   15:04:36.818 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  15:04:36.818
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   15:04:36.818 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more
>   help at https://help.gradle.org 15:04:36.818 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]  15:04:36.819
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD
>   FAILED in 5s

Comment: Please let me know if you found a more efficient solution than the one provided below.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar java compilation issue with version (1.8.0_152-release) but mine dealt with assertion errors on **Lambda** method conversions. Reverting to java version 1.7  for compilation worked for me. You can update the Target / Source compatibility in the (Module) **build.gradle** like so,

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

OR by clicking on your **File** tab on android studio --> then **Project Structure** and find 1.7 under the Source / Target Compatibility drop-down menu

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why, but like you say, it works and compiles. But, this error appears (https://stackoverflow.com/q/60949209/6723193) and says that I need to return to 1.8...

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue and my solution is changing jvmTarget to Java 11

```java
  android {
    kotlinOptions {
        //jvmTarget = '1.8'
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem. I got the error while my compileSdkVersion is set to 30. I am still searching for a solution.

Comment: @RealSollyM just encountered it. If you do find a solution, please post it and tag me. I'll be sure to do the same

Comment: Did anyone get a solution to this problem? I am still facing it in my flutter app