# An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_242-release). Please file a bug against the Java compiler - Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I build a flutter project about a year ago. I have updated the flutter version since then. I reopened it today but got the following error. Using [FVM](https://fvm.app/), I tried to run a project to the previous version that I think on which that project is built.
I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162522/android-studio-an-exception-has-occurred-in-the-compiler-1-8-0-152-release#) but its verified answer of adding following in build.gradle is not working for me

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

This how my `buid.gradle` looks like

```
android {
...
    compileSdkVersion 29
    // compileOptions {
    //   sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    //   targetCompatibility = 1.7
    // }
    ....
  
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId xxxxxx
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    ....
}
```

**Error**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N970F in debug mode...
    Parameter format not correct -
    An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_242-release). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
    java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitVarDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1164)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:852)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitClassDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1042)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$1.run(TypeAnnotations.java:127)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:152)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        
        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
        > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
        
        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
        
        * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
        
        BUILD FAILED in 26s
        Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
        Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you come up with a solution yet?

Comment: Same here. Any luck?

Comment: Any luck here, please? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score -4):

Run

```
flutter doctor -v
```

And check about failed log. For me, I installed a beta version of Android studio and my flutter doctor looked like
[Screenshort of my flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOIX4.png)

Comment: After that, you update your build.gradle and app/build.gradle files. Work for me